# How to copy file through Shutil python

Tags: python

I was trying to copy file from my desktop to System32 dir. it give me the following error.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'C:/Windows/System32/abc.exe'
```

here is my code

```
    src = pth + "\\" +s_name
    dist = "C:/Windows/System32/"
    shutil.copy(src , dist)
```

Comment: _it gives me the following error._ Alright, have you done any debugging? That error message seems rather clear to me, no?

Comment: why would you want to mess with the System32 directory in the first place? Also, try to avoid things like `src = pth + "\\" +s_name` - have a look at how to properly handle paths in Python, e.g. with the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module.

Comment: pth = "C:\Users\Turtle\Desktop\new project"

s_name = "abc.exe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with Python or shutil. Permission denied means that the user that runs the Python script does not have a permission to copy the file to `C:/Windows/System32`.

I think what you could do now is to look for a way to run the script as Windows administrator.